# how i update inbuilt model (user) in strongLoop using mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, strongloop, auto-update, loopback

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/usWiC.png)
i upload image here you can see whole folder structure.. 
In StrongLoop Framework there not visible User model in common/model folder so it's difficult to how i add property in user model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a new `model` which inherits `user` model. You can only make the changes that model and not the existing `user` model.